# Round numbers before statement

Tags: if-statement, printf, rounding

how can i round number on 5 decimal numbers of some result ?
I have something like this...

```
double s;
s=d/a;s1=d1/a1;
here i need to round these 2 numbers ... because s1 is different from s by 0.00000002 etc
if(s1>s){
printf("S1 > S");
    if(s1==s){
printf("S1 = S");
```

someone with help with this ? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

> Round numbers before (compare) statement

Scale by 100,000, round to a whole number and then compare.

No need to divide by the scaling and introduce more computational errors in order to compare.

```
#include <math.h>
int compare_rounded(double a, double b, double scale) {
  // or use round(), nearby()
  a = rint(a*scale);
  b = rint(b*scale);   
  return (a > b) - (a < b);   
}
```

**OR** perhaps more simply subtract.  This gives slight different results.  All depends what OP wants.

```
int compare_rounded2(double a, double b, double guard) {
  double diff = a-b;
  if (diff < -guard) return -1;
  return diff > guard;
}
```

then call one of the 2

```
double s  =d/a; 
double s1 =d1/a1;
int cmp = compare_rounded(s1,s, 100000.0);
// or 
int cmp = compare_rounded2(s1,s, 100000.0);
if (cmp > 0) {
  puts("S1 > S");
} else if (cmp == 0) {
  puts("S1 == S");
} else {
  puts("S1 < S");
}
```

To cope with both numbers near the same limit of `double` like `DBL_MAX`, additional code is needed is the first function due to `a*scale` overflow.